# Direct summand of a Motive

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $M(X)$ and $M(Y)$ be two Chow motives and suppose that $M(X)$ is a direct summand of $M(Y)$. Do we have that $M(X)(i)$ is a direct summand of $M(Y)(i)$, where $M(X)(i)$ is the twist by the Lefschetz motive?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because tensor products commute with direct sums. It's simply take the cycle that gives you the splitting and take the product with $(\mathbb P^1)^i$. This gives a splitting twisted by $i$.